# Haskell pattern matching error with data constructor

Tags: haskell

I have the following code in Haskell:

```
module testData where

import SImpL
changeName :: String -> String -> ProgT -> ProgT
...
changeName x y (Seq []) = Seq[]
changeName x y (Seq (oneStatement:moreStatements)) = Seq (changeName x y oneStatement : changeName x y (Seq moreStatements))
```

The definition of ProgT is defined in the module SImpL:

```
data StmtT = Assign NameT AExprT |   
             If BExprT StmtT StmtT | 
             While BExprT StmtT | 
             Seq [StmtT] -- If the list is empty, this is a statement that does nothing.    
             deriving (Show,Eq)

type ProgT = StmtT
```

Put simply, Seq[StmtT] is a list of Assign, If or While statements defined in the constructor.  ***The function changeName checks if there are variables in ALL statements that equal to x, and replaces it with y.***  When I run the code, I get the following error:

> Assignment3.hs:12:89: error:
>       • Couldn't match type ‘StmtT’ with ‘[ProgT]’
>         Expected type: [ProgT]
>           Actual type: ProgT
>       • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
>           ‘changeName x y (Seq moreStatements)’
>         In the first argument of ‘Seq’, namely
>           ‘(changeName x y oneStatement
>             : changeName x y (Seq moreStatements))’
>         In the expression:
>           Seq
>             (changeName x y oneStatement : changeName x y (Seq moreStatements))

Based on the error message, the problem is in the last line:

changeName x y (Seq (oneStatement:moreStatements)) = Seq(changeName x y oneStatement:**changeName x y (Seq moreStatements)**)

I can see why it would throw the error, but I have to recurse through each statement to change every variable in the statements.  Apologies if this is trivial, but I don't know I could recurse through Seq[StmtT] types without the error.

*note:* I don't think it matters what the other data types are (i.e. BExprT), just in case here is more of the module:

```
module SImpL where

data AExprT = ALit ValT -- a literal value (an Int)
              | AName NameT -- a variable name (a String)
              | Add AExprT AExprT -- one arithmetic expression added to another
              | Sub AExprT AExprT -- one arithmetic expression subtracted from another
              | Mult AExprT AExprT -- one arithmetic expression multiplied by another
              deriving (Show,Eq)

data BExprT = BLit Bool -- a literal value (True or False)
              | Eq AExprT AExprT -- an equality test between two arithmetic expressions
              | Less AExprT AExprT -- a "less than" test between two arithmetic expressions
              | Greater AExprT AExprT -- a "greater than" test between two arithmetic expressions
              | Not BExprT -- the negation of a boolean expression
              | And BExprT BExprT -- the "and" of two boolean expressions
              | Or BExprT BExprT -- the "or" of two boolean expressions
              deriving (Show,Eq)

type ValT = Integer

type NameT = String 

data StmtT = Assign NameT AExprT |   
             If BExprT StmtT StmtT | 
             While BExprT StmtT | 
             Seq [StmtT] -- If the list is empty, this is a statement that does nothing.    
             deriving (Show,Eq)  

If BExprT StmtT StmtT | 
             While BExprT StmtT | 
             Seq [StmtT] -- If the list is empty, this is a statement that does nothing.    
             deriving (Show,Eq)

type ProgT = StmtT 

type StateT = [(NameT, ValT)]
```

**EDIT:** @Ben Using map helped get around the error (since the function does not return a list now).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
changeName x y (Seq (oneStatement:moreStatements)) = Seq(changeName x y oneStatement:changeName x y Seq(moreStatements))
```

Should be:

```
changeName x y (Seq (oneStatement:moreStatements)) = Seq (changeName x y oneStatement : changeName x y (Seq moreStatements))
```

Specifically the problem is that the last part where you have `changeName x y Seq(moreStatements)` is seen as applying `changeName` to 4 arguments:

1. `x`
2. `y`
3. `Seq`
4. `(moreStatements)`

`Seq(moreStatements)` doesn't mean "apply `Seq` to `moreStatements`, as it would in a language with C-like syntax, but is rather just the terms `Seq` `(moreStatements)` next to each other, completely equivalent to if you had written `Seq moreStatements` because the parentheses are not needed to group a single identifier. If `Seq` was the "head" of that sub-expression it would do what you want, but it follows on `changeName x y`, so that is applied to `Seq`, and then to `moreStatements`, which doesn't fit the type of `changeName`.

(Note that this is pretty much exactly what the error message said)

---

Your second error is that `changeNames` has type `String -> String -> ProgT -> ProgT` (and remember `ProgT = StmtT`). But you use the result of `changeName` on the right side of `:`, as if it returned a **list** of something.

Probably you need to instead `changeName` over the list, rather than applying it to the head and to the tail? In fact you wouldn't even need to pattern match on the list then, you could just:

```
changeName x y (Seq statements) = Seq (map (changeName x y) statements)
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still run into an error when I change up the brackets, namely this: Couldn't match type ‘StmtT’ with ‘[ProgT]’
Expected type: [ProgT]
        Actual type: ProgT
    • In the second argument of ‘(:)’, namely
        ‘changeName x y (Seq moreStatements)’

Comment: @RosaryLightningX I've edited my answer to address that too, although its technically a totally separate error that was just masked by the first one.

Comment: ah, yes, changing the method certainly helped--now the pattern matching compiles correctly.  I did not think of using map at all vs head and tail, thanks so much for the insight.